# Allow Lambda to access local Sail DB environment

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I have a lambda function running in AWS and I want to take the output of that function and write it to a database. I'm not quite ready to deploy yet, where it would be writing to an RDS instance and presumably would be trivial to accomplish. Locally I'm using Laravel Sail and I'd like to be able to write the results to the database there.

Is that possible, and how would I do it? Would I be better off just grabbing the results and manually out of AWS and putting them in my local DB while developing? It's not ideal, but it would work if exposing my local db would be some kind of massive endeavor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible, and how would I do it?

Only if you want to expose your local database on the public Internet somehow. It might require some port forwarding in your home's internet router.

> Would I be better off just grabbing the results and manually out of
> AWS and putting them in my local DB while developing?

Yes absoutely.